# psql search specific word

Tags: sql, regex, psql

I am looking for the following expression specifically but I do not obtain it

I've tried the following

```
SELECT regexp_replace('KR 733 asd 12 12 NO SUR', '([^0-9]+)', ' ', 'g') || regexp_replace('KR 733 asd 12 12 NO SUR', '[^(SUR|ESTE)]', ' ', 'g')
```

the result it is

```
" 733 12 12  R                  SUR"
```

But I need it is **Only three number and the words (SUR|ESTE)**

```
" 733 12 12 SUR"
```

Another case

"CL 23 AS 343A 34 ESTE" => "23 343 34 ESTE"

"CL 23 AS 343A 34 50 30 ESTE" => "23 343 34 ESTE"

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this regex

```
SELECT regexp_replace('KR 733 asd 12 12 NO SUR', '([a-zA-Z]+)[^(?:\d|SUR|ESTE)]', ' ', 'g')
```

But it will keep any numbers presented in the string with SUR or ESTE at the end.